# Dynamic vector of contiguously allocated objects in the Heap

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory

I am trying to build a class to manage a std::vector<T*> of pointers to objects that must be contiguously allocated in the heap.

The problem I encountered is that building the vector as shown below leads to non contiguously allocated objects:

```
std::vector<T*> objects{};
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) objects.push_back(new T());
```

This is because two consecutive executions of `new T()` do not have to produce contiguous objects in memory. So the solution is to use `new[]` operator instead, which yielded me to this implementation:

```
template<class T>
class HeapVector
{
private:
  std::vector<T*> elems_{};
  const size_t BUFFER_SIZE_{}; // Buffer size
  size_t idx_{}; // Index controlling the index local to the buffer.
  T * buffer_ = nullptr; // Buffer

public:
  HeapVector() = default;
  HeapVector(const size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 256) : BUFFER_SIZE_(BUFFER_SIZE) {};


  void emplace_back() // TODO: Should pass constructor parameters or even a constructor
  {
    if (!(elems_.size() % BUFFER_SIZE_))
    {
      idx_ = 0;
      buffer_ = new T[BUFFER_SIZE_];
      elems_.reserve(elems_.size() + BUFFER_SIZE_);
    }
    
    // TODO: Object constructor. Must initialize buffer_[idx]
    // createElement(buffer_[idx], parameters...);
    elems_.push_back(buffer_ + idx_++);
  }

};
```

By executing `new T[BUFFER_SIZE_]`, I get a pointer to the first element of a contigously allocated array of BUFFER_SIZE_ elements built by using the Default Constructor.

What I want to achieve is, after this allocation is done, initialize this object with the desired parameters / another constructor (see TODOs). Also, I would like to avoid Copy Constructors.

Given that I want this class to be a templated class, what's the most generic way of achieve this?

Comment: Sound like you might want to use [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

Comment: "_pointers to objects that must be contiguously allocated in the heap._" - then why store pointers? Why not `std::vector<T>`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, that's what I had before this idea arised in my head, but because of the code logic (a lot of copies and duplications), I need to save memory by only have one copy of each object, and different vectors containing pointers to those objects. Summarizing, I need a bunch of vectors containing different objects based on the object characteristics, but I want to avoid object duplication (memory problems)

Comment: I don't see why you would need to create more objects just because you store them directly in the vector instead of storing a pointer to each object.

Comment: Your vector can be the owner of the objects. As long as it is not resized, copied or deeply modified (removal/insertion of elements), you can ensure the iterators/pointers on it are not invalidated. You can control the copies with a `std::unique_ptr` and the resizes with a `std::vector::resize` of the good size done only once. Furthermore, the modulus of `BUFFER_SIZE_ ` will cause your final implementation to be very slow (modulus are very expensive).

Comment: @JérômeRichard, the logic of the main program forces me to have several vectors containing different instances of each one of the objects, and I do not want to have copies, so the solution is to use pointers. But for the shake of performance, I want to force those pointers to points to contigously allocated memory. Also, I do not want to have a mix of std::vector<T> and std::vector<T*>.

Comment: @AlanWik Having one implementation of a vector with pointers that can be both owning and non-owning seems like a much bigger  issue to work around compared to having one single `std::vector<T>` (the owning vector) and a bunch of `std::vector<T*>` that just points to the objects in the first one.

Comment: @AlanWik saw this post about an [object pool](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/259414/c-object-pool-that-returns-a-smart-pointer-on-request) yesterday. Probably not exactly what you are looking for, but maybe it can give you some ideas.

Comment: If you create a `buffer` as an empty `vector<T>`, call `buffer.reserve(BUFFER_SIZE_)`, and `emplace_back` elements, then, you don't need any copies. It's still much better then calling `new[]` manually, which will always default-construct. Alternatively, you can use an _uninitialized storege_ (properly aligned) and construct elements inside manually (by _placement new_ or `std::construct_at`). But this will require much more effort and it will be error-prone without RAII.

Comment: What's the difference between your `HeapVector` and a `std::vector`? What advantage does is bring? As already described by others: Use a `std::vector` as object pool to store your objects and use indexes instead of pointers to access the objects.

Comment: "_I do not want to have a mix of `std::vector<T>` and `std::vector<T*>`_" - Why? The one with `T` would be the owning one and the rest of them could store `T*`. As long as the owning `vector` doesn't need to reallocate it shoul be safe, If it has to reallocate, you need to recreate the pointer vectors.

Comment: To add to @TedLyngmo's comment: Moreover, if you use indexes instead of pointers, you are safe either with vector reallocation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::vector` as object pool to store your objects and use indexes instead of pointers to access the objects:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Object {
    std::string name;
    std::size_t age;

    Object(const std::string &n, std::size_t a): name(n), age(a) {}
};

template<typename T>
class Pool;

template<typename T>
class ObjectRef {
    Pool<T> &pool;
    std::size_t index;
    ObjectRef(Pool<T> &p, std::size_t i): pool(p), index(i) {}
public:
    friend Pool<T>;
    T &operator*() {
        return pool.buffer[index];
    }
    T *operator->() {
        return &pool.buffer[index];
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Pool {
    std::vector<T> buffer;
public:
    friend ObjectRef<T>;
    Pool(std::size_t s = 250) {
        buffer.reserve(s);
    }
    
    template<typename... Ts>
    ObjectRef<T> newObject(Ts ...args) {
        buffer.emplace_back(args...);
        return ObjectRef<T>(*this, buffer.size() - 1);
    }
};

int main() {
    Pool<Object> objectPool(250);
    auto objectRef = objectPool.newObject("Name", 30);
    std::cout << objectRef->name;
    Pool<int> intPool(250);
    auto intRef = intPool.newObject(30);
    std::cout << *intRef;
}
```