# C++; Working with pointers into a container

Tags: c++, pointers, containers

Recently I tried to implement a simple algorithm in C++ using containers and I ran into a behavior I did not expect and I can not explain. I am new to work with containers so it is possible that the explanation is simple but I just can not see it now.

So, I have a structure to represent a Point that is as simple as:

```
struct Point{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
```

and a simple function for its printing

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, const Point p){
    os << "x= "<<p.x << " y= "<<p.y << " z= "<<p.z;
    return os;
}
```

Now, in a certain part of the code, I allocate a vector of Points of certain size and fill it.

```
vector<Point>* points = new vector<Point>(number_of_lines);

for (int i = 0; i < number_of_lines; i++){
    (*points)[i] = some_data;
}
```

Later in the code I call

```
Point* new_point = function_g(points); 
cout<<"Outside the function1 : " << *new_point<<endl;
cout<<"Outside the function2 : " << *new_point<<endl;
```

where the `function_g` is defined (somewhat) as:

```
Point* function_g(vector<Point>* points){
    Point* out;
    int len = points->size();

   for(int j = 0; j<len; j++){
       Point i = points->at(j);
       if (some_condition){
            out = &i;
       }
    }

    cout << "In the function: " << *out<<endl;
    return out;
}
```

So in this `function_g` I intend to iterate over the points and find one that fits a condition (I know there is one there) and then I want to return a pointer to the point so I can work with it further in the code. However, when I run the code, I get:

```
In the function: x= 0.1 y= 0.1 z= 0.1
Outside the function: x= 0.1 y= -8.69944e+32 z= 0.1
Outside the function: x= 4.67894e-310 y= -8.69944e+32 z= 4.94066e-324
```

so in the function, I get right results when using the pointer, however outside they go wrong and the pointed memory is corrupted. Can anyone explain me, please, what is happening?

Comment: `Point i = points->at(j);` makes a copy of the item in the vector, then you return the address of that copy. The copy is destroyed when the function ends and accessing that memory is undefined behaviour.

Comment: even if it doesn't make a local copy take a pointer of an element in a vector is still not safe because the vector can grow and reallocate the memory

Comment: @Adam, the style of the code in your example is not what it is recommended in modern C++, the new operator should be seldomly used. In fact, raw pointer in general are not the norm at all

Comment: It is very rare to need to allocate a `std::vector` dynamically. They already store their internal data dynamically.

Comment: I think it does, thank you! And is there a way to get a pointer onto the vector's element instead of its copy?

Comment: Of course there is. But as soon as another value gets added to the vector that pointer will no longer be valid, unless some very, very specific steps get taken in advance.

Comment: It would be better to return the index of the item in the vector.

Comment: Keeping a pointer to the element of a `std:::vector` is potentially dangerous. If you change the size of the vector you invalidate any pointers to its elements.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67073005/15388024) you can see an example code for a reference to a vector element. The reference contains the index and a reference to the vector instead of the memory address. This way the vector can relocate the elements and your reference stays valid. It's in the `ObjectRef` class.